# How to print the value of an element?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I want to print the text value of an element to the console for debugging purposes.  I have:

```
var result = element(by.model('vm.firstName')).getAttribute('value');
console.log('first name is: ' + result.getInnerHtml() + result.getOuterHtml() + result.getText() + "" + result.getId() + Object.keys(result));
expect(result).toBe('Colin');
```

The expectation passes.  The log does not give me "Colin" as I desire:

> first name is: [object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]ptor_,parentElementArrayFinder,then,elementArrayFinder_,click,sendKeys,getTagName,getCssValue,getAttribute,getText,getSize,getLocation,isEnabled,isSelected,submit,clear,isDisplayed,getOuterHtml,getInnerHtml,getId,getRawId

How can I get the name to display instead of [object Object]?

Comment: have you tried just logging the result object, nothing else, Most modern browsers will recognize this as an object and will let you explore the object in the log window.

Comment: @Delta - yea sorry that is not in the question.  I have tried it and got `[object Object]`

Comment: it looks like getAttribute('value') is going to return a string and then you are calling. result.getInnerHtml() on a stringliteral. But that doesnt coincide with your [object object] results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time when you're trying to log the result, it is still an unresolved promise. Try the following:

```
var result = element(by.model('vm.firstName')).getAttribute('value');
//the .then statement will only execute once the promise has been resolved.
result.then(function(foo){
    console.log('first name is: ' + foo.getInnerHtml() + foo.getOuterHtml() + result.getText() + "" + foo.getId() + Object.keys(foo));
});
```